# Databases and tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

So I'm making a quiz app and I need to design a database to store data.
My initial design was 3 tables to store the Questions, Answers and Quizzes.

Table 1 Questions:
Index ID, Title, Questions, Hint, Topic

Table 2 Answers:
Index ID, Questions ID, Answer, Correct(Boolean)

Table 3 Quiz:
Index ID, Quiz Name, Quiz Discription, Question List(By ids)

So my dilemma is this.A question might have 2-50 answers some of them correct and some of them not(indicated by the Correct(boolean).Because of this should I have a different table for each question or just have one giant answer table?
I know for a small table it makes no difference, but let's say we have 100 000 questions and each question has around 30 answers, this would make the answer database huge and querying for a list of answers for one question would probably take some time.So would it be better to have 100 000 separate tables with the answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's generally better to have a table of 3 million rows. This is well within the capability of MySQL.

In the system I currently manage, we have one table with over *5 billion* rows, more than a thousand times larger than the one you anticipate. At this scale, we need to be careful how we index and partition it to make queries optimized.

Comment: The thing I'm worried about is.Let's say I want to get all the answers for question id 1.The database would have to look trough 3m rows to find all of them.Is than not a problem?

Comment: If you want to find a phone number in a telephone book, do you have to read the whole book? No, you can find the name of the person you're looking for pretty quickly, because the book is stored in sorted order. This is analogous to an *index* in a database. It's something you should learn about. You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really).

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though your Questions and Answers have a many to many relationship. You could have many answers that could be a potential correct answer for multiple questions, if I understand correctly. And conversely, your questions can have many answers. Instead of a table for each question, I suggest you make a fourth table coordinating what answers belong to which questions. This would allow you to specify which answer is correct and not correct for every question isolated from the Answer table. You would have composite keys in this table.

Perhaps something like:

QuestionAnswers: (Questions)Index ID, (Answers)Index ID, Correct(Boolean)

Questions: Index ID, Title, Questions, Hint, Topic

Answers: Index ID, Answer

Quiz: Index ID, Quiz Name, Quiz Discription, Question List(By ids)

Comment: I guess if I did make a 4th table it would also allow me to use the same answer for multiple questions.Other than that I don't understand the need for the 4th table.